# Multi-table MySQL query returning too many results

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I need to do a SELECT in 8 tables, but the results in not what I have expected.

**The ugly code:**

```
SELECT equipment.*
FROM equipment
LEFT JOIN equip_adaptador  a ON (a.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
LEFT JOIN equip_antena aa ON (aa.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
LEFT JOIN equip_cable c ON (c.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
LEFT JOIN equip_conector cc ON (cc.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
LEFT JOIN equip_fonte f ON (f.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
LEFT JOIN equip_router r ON (r.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
LEFT JOIN equip_suporte s ON (s.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
WHERE equipment.cod_equip = 'EC726026316A0'
```

*the results is 63 items, is not right.*

Explainig the code above:

My table `equipment` is my **master table**, there I have the `cod_equip field` (a master field to all my slave tables).

All my **slave table** I had gave a prefix called `equip_` (*are 7 slave tables in the total*)

Now I need a `SELECT` to `JOIN` all the 8 tables.

**Adding more:**

I was expecting 9 rows, but it fetched 63 rows, I need to show something like this: **table equipment** (only 1 row) and other tables the respect number of it owns.

For example **equip_adaptador** was two times inserted with the same **cod_equip**, then I need to show it..

This query is the same as if I do one by one query to see what I have with the **equipment.cod_equip = 'EC726026316A0'**

Just it!

Thanks in advance people!

Comment: What makes you think it is not right? How many rows are you expecting?

Comment: What is the expected result? Edit: Aww beat me by 25 seconds

Comment: @Dismissile I was expecting 9 rows, but it fetched 63 rows, I need to show something like this:  equipment (only 1 row) and other tables the respect number of it owns. For example equip_adaptador was two times inserted with the same cod_equip, then I need to show it..

Comment: Try adding the contents of the results ur looking for...maybe an example of the  equipment row that uv added as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that each row returned from a child table is matched with every row returned from the other child tables.

You have one parent row returned, as you expect.

But if one of the child tables has seven (7) matching rows, and another child table has nine (9) matching rows, you are getting 7*9=63 rows returned.

This is the expected resultset, per the SQL specification.

Here is a test case that demonstrates what is happening:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id INT);
CREATE TABLE c1 (id INT, t_id INT);
CREATE TABLE c2 (id INT, t_id INT);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO c1 VALUES (11,1),(12,1);
INSERT INTO c2 VALUES (21,1),(22,1);

SELECT t.id, c1.id AS c1, c2.id AS c2
FROM t
JOIN c1 ON (t.id = c1.t_id)
JOIN c2 ON (t.id = c2.t_id)

id  c1   c2
--  ---  ---
1   11   21
1   12   21
1   11   22
1   12   22
```

Note that the rows from c1 are repeated, once for each row from c2. Likewise for the rows from c2.

This is exactly the result set we expect.

If we don't want a cross join (cartesian product) of the child rows, we can run separate queries:

```
SELECT t.id, c1.id AS c1
FROM t
JOIN c1 ON (t.id = c1.t_id) 

SELECT t.id, c2.id AS c2
FROM t
JOIN c2 ON (t.id = c2.t_id)

id  c1
--  ---
1   11
1   12

id  c2
--  ---
1   21
1   22
```

That's one way to avoid generating "repeated" child rows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, I understood what was happening and right now I will use a multi select (run separate queries) to show what I need, I think is the only way. Your response was accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Your ON clauses should have constraints on the tables that you are joining.  Currently they don't.  So, for instance, you're joining equip_fonte on all cases where equip_adaptador.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip.  And the truth of that statement has nothing to do with what is happening in equip_fonte.

Comment: Good eye. Didn't even notice that :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ur table names on join conditions are wrong...
Try this

```
SELECT equipment.*
    FROM equipment
    LEFT JOIN equip_adaptador  a ON (a.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
    LEFT JOIN equip_antena aa ON (aa.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
    LEFT JOIN equip_cable c ON (c.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
    LEFT JOIN equip_conector cc ON (cc.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
    LEFT JOIN equip_fonte f ON (f.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
    LEFT JOIN equip_router r ON (r.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
    LEFT JOIN equip_suporte s ON (s.cod_equip = equipment.cod_equip)
    WHERE equipment.cod_equip = 'EC726026316A0'
```

Comment: I had posted the wrong sql code, sorry, but you fix the table names, thanks. Your code return to me 113 rows, still wrong the result I'm looking for..

Comment: @Fernando Costa : ur doing a left outer join...which will return all rows in equipment table..are u looking for normal join instead?

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN return to me the same result as LEFT JOIN.  

with only JOIN returns to me an error.