# MYSQL optimisation in a JOIN query where ON condition returns multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am looking for the best way to extract datas from multiple tables where each tables returns multiple rows.

Here is what I get for the moment :

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ([id] => 1 [0] => 1 [comment] => My first Iphone ! [1] => My first Iphone ! [name] => Seb [2] => Seb [type] => smartphone [3] => smartphone [cat] => Phone [4] => Phone [fields] => Brand [5] => Brand [value] => Apple [6] => Apple )

[1] => Array ([id] => 1 [0] => 1 [comment] => My first Iphone ! [1] => My first Iphone ! [name] => Seb [2] => Seb [type] => smartphone [3] => smartphone [cat] => Phone [4] => Phone [fields] => Model [5] => Model [value] => Apple [6] => Apple )

[2] => Array ( [id] => 1 [0] => 1 [comment] => My first Iphone ! [1] => My first Iphone ! [name] => Seb [2] => Seb [type] => smartphone [3] => smartphone [cat] => Phone [4] => Phone [fields] => Brand [5] => Brand [value] => Iphone 5S [6] => Iphone 5S )

[3] => Array ( [id] => 1 [0] => 1 [comment] => My first Iphone ! [1] => My first Iphone ! [name] => Seb [2] => Seb [type] => smartphone [3] => smartphone [cat] => Phone [4] => Phone [fields] => Model [5] => Model [value] => Iphone 5S [6] => Iphone 5S ) )
```

I get 4 rows since JOIN is making a Cartesian product between tables and 2 of JOIN queries returns 2 results each.

Here is the structure :

*purchases :*

```
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+---------------------+--------+
| id | comment                              | pictures | user | date                | object |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | Mon premier Iphone ! la classe ! :-p |     NULL |   18 | 2014-02-24 06:33:08 |      1 |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+---------------------+--------+
```

*object*

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | type | date                |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 |    1 | 2014-02-25 00:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

object_type

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | name       | category |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | smartphone |        2 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

Category

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| id | name        | parent |
+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 | High-Tech   |   NULL |
|  2 | Téléphone   |      1 |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

object_type_fields

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | name    | required |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | Marque  |        1 |
|  2 | Modèle  |        1 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

object_type_fields_type

```
+---------+----------+
| id_type | id_field |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |
|       1 |        2 |
+---------+----------+
```

fields_values

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | id_fields | value     |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 | Apple     |
|  2 |         2 | Iphone 5S |
|  3 |         1 | SAMSUNG   |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

object_fields_values

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | id_object | id_value |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 |         1 |        1 |
|  2 |         1 |        2 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Here is my query :

```
SELECT
                purchases.id,
                purchases.comment as "comment",
                users.name as "name",
                object_type.name as "type",
                category.name as "cat",
                object_type_fields.name as "fields",
                fields_values.value as "value"
            FROM purchases
                JOIN object ON purchases.object = object.id
                JOIN object_type ON object.type = object_type.id
                JOIN category ON object_type.category = category.id
                JOIN object_type_fields_type ON object_type.id = object_type_fields_type.id_type
                JOIN object_type_fields ON object_type_fields_type.id_field = object_type_fields.id
                JOIN object_fields_values ON object_fields_values.id_object = object.id
                JOIN fields_values ON fields_values.id = object_fields_values.id_value
                JOIN users ON users.id = purchases.user
            WHERE users.username = :username
```

Here is what I would like to have at the end:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ([id] => 1 [0] => 1 [comment] => My first Iphone ! [1] => My first Iphone ! [name] => Seb [2] => Seb [type] => smartphone [3] => smartphone [cat] => Phone [4] => Phone [fields] => Array([Brand] => Apple,  [Model] => Iphone 5S )))
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122433/multi-table-mysql-query-returning-too-many-results) that multiple queries were a way to do that (the only way?).

But... here is my problem : making 2 queries (getting fields and getting values) for each rows that the first query gives me does not seems to be very efficient... number of queries will grow up very fast depending on the number of objects first query will return...

Another solution I can see is to re-construct an array using php based on the array Mysql gives me. But still... it is too much loop for only one object.

Is there a MYSQL tools/function/way to get what I want efficiently?

I first thought about serializing the [fields]=>value array in the objects table but I will have the same efficiency problem when searching datas by value (for example).

Comment: Can you post your SQL, or at least how the tables relate to each other.

Comment: Additionally, show some actual data values in the tables (not the array listing) and show... ex: 5-10 rows per table to get the context across.  Additionally, show what you are EXPECTING to get out of it, and agree with Kickstart on showing the SQL you are running now.

Comment: Thx for your comments. I just add what you asked me.

Comment: By the way, my query is doing exactly was I was expecting : a Cartesian product. But I cannot manage that type of result to show each object with each fields and values from the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly get what you want, as you are trying to get an array of php arrays from MySQL.

Best you can do would be to use concat_ws / group_concat to get the values out on one line.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT
    purchases.id,
    purchases.comment as "comment",
    users.name as "name",
    object_type.name as "type",
    category.name as "cat",
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS("|", object_type_fields.name,fields_values.value)) as "fieldvalue"
FROM purchases
    JOIN object ON purchases.object = object.id
    JOIN object_type ON object.type = object_type.id
    JOIN category ON object_type.category = category.id
    JOIN object_type_fields_type ON object_type.id = object_type_fields_type.id_type
    JOIN object_type_fields ON object_type_fields_type.id_field = object_type_fields.id
    JOIN object_fields_values ON object_fields_values.id_object = object.id
    JOIN fields_values ON fields_values.id = object_fields_values.id_value
    JOIN users ON users.id = purchases.user
WHERE users.username = :username
GROUP BY purchases.id,
    comment,
    name,
    type,
    cat
```